# Django reset_password_confirm TemplateSyntaxError problem

Tags: django, django-templates

when I use **django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm** without arguments at all it works and I can render the template without any problem, when adding uidb36 and token arguments it fails.

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb36': '111', 'token': '1111111111111'}' not found.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most likely it is an issue with your urls.py.  You need to setup the right pattern to grab the uidb36 and token values passed as URL parameters.  If not, it will throw a similar error to what you see above.

Something like:

```
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'template_name' : 'registration/password_reset.html',  'post_reset_redirect': '/logout/' })
```

registration/password_reset.html - is my custom template

*logout* - is my custom logout action

Comment: It seems absurd for something built-in to Django to not have this kind of information on their official documentation site. Either way thanks for this answer! Still helpful nearly two years later

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue in Django 1.3, and wasted a lot of time because the error can mask a number of underlying issues.

I needed to add this to the top of the reset email template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

Also, the example in the Django docs didn't match the sample url:

```
{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url 'auth_password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
```

So I had to change the `auth_password_reset_confirm` above to `password_reset_confirm`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Django 1.6+ and run into something like this it could be that you need to update uidb36 to uidb64 in both your template and your urls.

Example url:

`url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_confirm`

and reset link in template:

`{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

Comment: Thanks!! this answer saved me a night of searching!!

Answer (score 2):

For Django 1.8+ users, just copy this URL to your main **urls.py** file, so that it recognizes the URL name

```
  url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

And add this mentioned by: @Lunulata to your **password_reset_email.html** file:

`{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url` `'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following to your urls.py

```
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work, copied from the default url

`url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your urls.py:

```
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

This enables the django reset_password workflow.

Then override your login.html to include the line:
`<div class="password-reset-link">
href="{{ password_reset_url }}">{% trans 'Forgotten your password or username?' %}</a></div>`

Now you should be able to use the builtin Django PasswordResetView included with Django as long as your email settings are set up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using app_name in every urls.py

suppose you have an app and in that app in urls.py you have mentioned app_name="accounts"
in order to retrieve the page you need to mention two things
template_name and success_url inside the PasswordResetView(template_name="accounts/password_reset.html" , success_url= reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_sent'))

dont forget to import reverse_lazy from django.urls inside urls.py

so your final code of accounts/urls.py should look like

> My app name is landing instead of accounts

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

app_name='landing'

urlpatterns = [
     path('',views.home,name="home"),
     path('terms/',views.terms,name="terms"),
     path('login/',views.loginUser,name="login"),
     path('signup/',views.signupUser,name="signup"),
     path('about/',views.about,name="about"),
     path('logout/',views.logoutUser,name="logout"),

     path('password_reset/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='landing/password_reset.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('landing:password_reset_done')),
               name="password_reset"),

     path('password_reset_sent/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='landing/password_reset_sent.html'),
          name="password_reset_done"),

     path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='landing/password_reset_form.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('landing:password_reset_complete')),
          name="password_reset_confirm"),

     path('password_reset_complete/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='landing/password_reset_done.html'),
          name="password_reset_complete"),

]
```

you have to use **app_name:** before the name of url you have mentioned it is very important