# Trigger password reset email in django without browser?

Tags: django, forms, passwords, reset

I want to be able to send a password reset email using django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset
but without using the browser - password_reset needs a populated form, is there a way I can create this programmatically and get the email sent?

Comment: "without browser" / "not without a browser".  What?

Comment: @S.Lott - Heh, question was terribly typed :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

def reset_password(email, from_email, template='registration/password_reset_email.html', domain_override="localhost:8000"):
    """
    Reset the password for all (active) users with the given E-Mail address
    """
    form = PasswordResetForm({'email': email})
    if form.is_valid():
        return form.save(from_email=from_email, email_template_name=template)
```

Comment: If you get a redirection error then you need to add the template to your urls, as mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790838/django-reset-password-confirm-templatesyntaxerror-problem

Comment: Note that in more recent version of Django (not entirely sure starting from which), you need to call `form.is_valid()` before `form.save()`

Comment: If you are calling form.save() from a view you might also need to pass the request as one of the parameters... form.save(request=request, ...)

Comment: You may need to add a "domain_override" kwarg to save if you aren't sending "request". As in ```form.save(from_email=from_email, mail_template_name=template, domain_override="localhost:8000")``` This prevents the ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_host'```

Comment: It sends plain text for me, instead of HTML via email, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

You can just use django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm and populate it with data like this:

```
form = PasswordResetForm({'email':'sample@sample.com'})
```

The sending of email is done upon save().