# How to programmatically trigger password reset email in django 1.7.6?

Tags: python, django, passwords, reset, programmatically-created

I've encountered a problem where I had to load more than 200 new users into my django app and right away send them a password reset email. This had to happen only once, done only by me and run quietly on backend. Surfing the internet brought me only to one more or less right answer: [Trigger password reset email in django without browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594197/trigger-password-reset-email-in-django-without-browser). The only problem was is that this post was about 4 years old and of course when I tried the solution, it didn't work...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two most valuable points from the link I mentioned:

1. In most recent version of Django, we need to call `form.is_valid()`
2. Sending of email is done upon `save()`.

Here is how I queried users that I needed and sent each of them a password reset link:

```
def find_users_and_send_email():
    from django.http import HttpRequest
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    users = User.objects.filter(date_joined__gt = '2015-04-16')
    for user in users:
        try:
            if user.email:
                logger.info("Sending email for to this email:", user.email)
                form = PasswordResetForm({'email': user.email})
                
                assert form.is_valid()
                request = HttpRequest()
                request.META['SERVER_NAME'] = 'help.mydomain.com'
                request.META['SERVER_PORT'] = '443'
                form.save(
                    request= request,
                    use_https=True,
                    from_email="username@gmail.com", 
                        email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html')

        except Exception as e:
            logger.warning(str(e))
            continue

    return 'done'
```

1. Usually `PasswordResetForm` works with a "request" from the front-end, which I didn't have. So I simply created one.
2. When I followed the example in the link, it failed.. It couldn't find server name in the request. (Makes sense because I instantiated my request out of nowhere)
3. When I fixed server name, it asked for the server port. Since I used https, my port is 443, otherwise, use default port.
4. If you use https, don't forget to indicate it when you save the form `use_https=True`

Comment: instead of creating a request, you can also just set `domain_override` within `form.save()` to whatever you want to be displayed as your domain within the reset email (this will be used both for the link and for the default subject of the email)

Comment: Note that if the email is for a non-existent/invalid user .save() will quietly skip sending the message and not raise an error. The solution for me was to preemptively call `next(form.get_users(users_email_address))` to check that the returned generator contains a match. BTW Fasand's idea of using `domain_override` worked for me! Nice

Answer (score 2):

I found it useful to wrap @chabislav's answer up in a custom management command which can then be reused as necessary. Note that I eliminated the user object filter, as I knew that I wanted to send password reset instructions to *all* users.

```
# myproject/myapp/management/commands/send_password_reset_emails.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
# I use a custom user model, so importing that rather than the standard django.contrib.auth.models
from users.models import User
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Emails password reset instructions to all users'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            try:
                if user.email:
                    print("Sending email for to this email:", user.email)
                    form = PasswordResetForm({'email': user.email})
                    assert form.is_valid()
                    request = HttpRequest()
                    request.META['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www.example.com'
                    request.META['SERVER_PORT'] = 443
                    form.save(
                        request= request,
                        use_https=True,
                        from_email="admin@mysite.com", 
                        email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'
                        )
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue

        return 'done'
```

This can then be run easily with `python manage.py send_password_reset_emails`.

Note that I got an error message `(550, b'5.7.1 Relaying denied')`, which ended up being an issue with the way that my localhost email server was set up, but once that was cleared this worked quite well. Having it in a management command is also nice because it doesn't clog up code that you use on a regular basis (views).

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this with django 3.x or 4.x AND are using django-allauth, this will work for you:

```py
from allauth.account.forms import ResetPasswordForm # note the different form import

form = ResetPasswordForm({"email": "some@mail.io"})

assert form.is_valid() # required because we need clean() executed
form.save(
    request=None,
    from_email="noreply@example.io",
)
```

Please note that this will take all values from the [allauth config](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), using `django.contrib.sites`.