# Programmatically trigger password reset in Django 3.2

Tags: python, django, django-forms

The method detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594197/trigger-password-reset-email-in-django-without-browser) no longer works. Importing `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm` results in the custom user class not being available (`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.CustomUser' that has not been installed`). How do I send these emails programmatically?

To avoid the X-Y Problem: I don't want user registration. I want admins to be able  to create users by supplying an email address, at which point the user receives a password reset email. Upon resetting (more accurately, creating) a password, the user can log in and set a display name and other attributes.

Comment: You haven't added the app `accounts` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting... (or perhaps a circular import)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AUTH\_USER\_MODEL refers to model .. that has not been installed and created AbstractUser models not able to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699598/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-that-has-not-been-installed-and-created-abstr)

Comment: No, the accounts app works fine without the import. Oddly, the app will actually run if I use, but do not import, the PasswordResetForm; however, it doesn't seem to actually reset the password on creation yet. I'm still working on that.