# Proper use of PasswordResetForm in Django

Tags: django, authentication, passwords, password-recovery

I'm trying to use django's supposed PasswordResetForm functionality to create a password reset form for my django application.

I created a form, in **forms.py**

```
class UserForgotPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,max_length=254)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email")
```

I'm having trouble setting up the `view` in **views.py** to utilize this form, I currently have:

```
def UserResetPassword(request):
    form = UserForgotPasswordForm(None, request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            user =
```

my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^ForgotPassword/$',UserResetPassword),
)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss of how to use this further as the documentation I've found is scarce and often not directly using `PasswordResetForm` django functionality.

Can someone lend a hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is call form.save() and the PasswordResetForm will generate a onetime use link and email it to the user for you. It looks up the user matching the e-mail entered into the form.

So it would be something like:

```
def UserResetPassword(request):
    form = UserForgotPasswordForm(None, request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(from_email='blah@blah.com', email_template_name='path/to/your/email_template.html')
```

If you don't specify an email template name, django will just use [the default one](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html).

Comment: will `email_template_name` look in my configured /templates dir?

Comment: Yes, you might need to configure your URLS though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790838/django-reset-password-confirm-templatesyntaxerror-problem if you're having issues.

Comment: so, `email_template_name` = path/to-template/<temp-up-to-15-char-name-here> ?

Comment: So something like `form.save(from_email='blah@blah.com', email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html')`. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: from_email=from_email , the second from_email will get that from the email field that the user enters, right?

Comment: Nope the email field is the user's email, who the email is getting sent **to**. The `from_email` is whatever address you want the email to be sent **from**. For example if you wanted them to be able to respond if they had issues, something like `support@yoursite.com`.

Comment: Please explain what the role of email_template_name is

Comment: Is email_template_name the template used to display the forgot password screen (with the user's email input) ? or?

Comment: It's the template for the email being sent to the user.

Comment: So, its an html template used in the email when sending?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L233 Maybe this will help :)

Comment: It isn't using the PasswordResetForm completely though

Comment: ??? That **is** PasswordResetForm. And to answer your question regarding what the email template is, it is the template used for the message body of the email being sent to the user to reset their password.

Comment: Actually, I should have looked at this more carefully. This is a great resource. Thank you Tim for your explanations!

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out! And Django is nice because you can always just look at the source directly if you're having issues or if the docs are lacking :)